# Unable to autowire bean in a class

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Below is the Configuration Class where I am defining the bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.billing.web.controllers", "com.abc.billing.core.services" })
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new BusinessUnitInterceptor());
  }

  @Bean
  public TripsExpiryTask tripsExpiryTask() {
    return new TripsExpiryTask();
  }

  @Bean
  public TripsExpiryJob tripsExpiryJob() {
    return new TripsExpiryJob();
  }

  @Bean
  public TripsExpiryJobTrigger tripsExpiryJobTrigger() throws SchedulerException {
    return new TripsExpiryJobTrigger();
  }

}
```

and for accessing the bean, I am autowiring it in another class(TripExpiryJob)

```
public class TripsExpiryJob implements Job {

  @Autowired
  TripsExpiryTask tripsExpiryTask;

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    tripsExpiryTask.execute();
  }
}
```

But it is unable to Autowire TripExpiryTask in TripExpiryJob Class.

Updated:

```
public class TripsExpiryTask {

    @Autowired
    BillableTripRepository btr;

    @Autowired
    BillableRequestRepository brr;

    public TripsExpiryTask() {
        System.out.println("Trips Expiry Job!");
    }

    private void updateProbableExpiredTrips(List<PBillableTrip> expiredTrips) {
    //Some Code
    }

    private void expireTrips() {
        // Some Code
    }

    public void execute() {
        expireTrips();
    }
}
```

Comment: The most important part of such questions is missing here: The error!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose There is no error coming up. Apparently it is not able to Autowired the above tripsExpiryTask in TripExpiryJob

Comment: The annotation [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) has a parameter ([`required`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html#required--)) which defaults to `true`. If your program is not able to autowire, you will get an exception. If not, then you are obviously not using that class as a _bean_.

Comment: But I have already defined the bean in Configuration class. Is there something i may be missing?

Comment: could you post the TripExpiryTask class source code aswell ? cause maybe its not a spring bean

Comment: @AntJavaDev I have updated the TripExpiryTask as well

Comment: is the TripExpiryTask and the TripsExpiryJob  , annotated with spring annotations , or at least are they context aware? because from the code snippet you shared , they do not look like spring beans

Comment: @AntJavaDev, look at the code `WebAppConfig`, the user is creating those as beans in `WebAppConfig` class.

Comment: @Chaitanya , yes , this is clear , the thing is how is the TripsExpiryJob get called in the runtime ? Archit , the wiring exception is getting thrown during application startup , or when the job trigger get called?

Comment: I have made a Trigger for running Job at regular intervals of time

Comment: You should get an exception when the spring's app context is created (during startup). How did you notice Spring is not autowiring TripsExpiryTask?

Comment: Since after @Autowiring tripsExpiryTask it is remaining a null value.

Comment: could you post the code for TripsExpiryJobTrigger . This is the triggered job right?

Comment: @ArchitMaheshwari, can you tell exactly where you saw the null value for the `tripsExpiryTask` property? As per your configuration there should not be any issue. If the `TripsExpiryJob` bean is available then its dependency is also injected correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in WebAppConfig class. I made a separate configuration class for job and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To initialized @Autowired objects, Make sure, that you are doing

<context:component-scan>

in configuration file.

If you are using Configuration class instead servlet-config.xml then you have to do

@ComponentScan on class level

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, It is now scanning the component but still it is assigning NULL value to the @Autowired.

Comment: check the below answer Archit

Answer (score 0):

Check the object you are autowiring is created in xml file.

<bean id="object" class="fully qualified name of your class" />

or to initialize automatically use

<context:annotation-config />